# finding a formula for a given truth table

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How would one proceed in finding a formula from a given truth table ***without*** resort to the use of disjunctive normal form and karnaugh maps?
For example, given

```
X  Y  Z  A
t  t  t  t
t  t  f  f
t  f  t  f
t  f  f  t
f  t  t  t
f  t  f  f
f  f  t  f
f  f  f  f
```

how can I find such a formula for $A$? I was given the hint to firstly look at the columns for $Y$ and $Z$, and I observed that it was two truth tables for $Y$ and $Z$ "embedded" in this truth table, so to speak. But I couldn't see the relevance of that.

Comment: Heard of SOP & POS?

Comment: I have in fact not.  I shall look it up now.

Comment: $(X\vee Y)\wedge(Y\leftrightarrow Z)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : find where the A values are true then find an equation using SOP or sum of products process and then simplify the equation if possible....

Edit : you seem quite new to this so $$A=xyz+x^|yz+x(yz)^|$$
This is how we express in SOP form. You can find such formula for any boolean variable

Try to give inputs I.e. x,y and z and find whether you get the correct results...Also try to simplify the above equation if possible....

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but after a bit of reading, isn't SOP the same as disjunctive normal form?

Comment: I don't remember what is it called but if it is the same then yes it is disjuctive normal form.

Comment: oh but I wanted a way to do it without the use of disjunctive normal form and karnaugh maps, sorry if that wasn't clear in the original post

Comment: I think all other ways of finding the variables function are similar to this one... not sure if there will be another way which would be much different than this

Comment: you are perhaps right. in fact I haven't seen any other methods. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Take the rows where $A=t$, and OR them:

```
X  Y  Z  A
t  t  t  t
t  f  f  t
f  t  t  t
```

$A=(X \wedge Y \wedge Z) \vee (X \wedge \neg Y \wedge \neg Z) \vee (\neg X \wedge Y \wedge Z)$